# SQL-Insert into multiple columns by having different select into queries

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union

I wanted to insert into a table with 4 columns. the first two columns will be populated by using a select into statement while the las two columns will be populated from two different tables. what I want to do is that all of it will be populated row by row with no duplicates and nulls.

To visualize my plan, here is the desired output:

[image]

but whenever i try doing it, this is what I get:

[image]

a null value for every insert. I am currently using a procedure and here is my query :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Biller`(IN Pid varchar(30))
BEGIN
    insert into sample2(ids,prices)
    select bed_bill_id,price 
    from bed_billing
    where patient_id = Pid
    UNION
    select csr_bill_id,price
    from csr_billing
    where patient_id = Pid
    UNION
    select lab_bill_id,price
    from lab_billing
    where patient_id = Pid
    UNION
    select pharm_bill_id,price
    from pharm_billing
    where patient_id = Pid
    UNION
    select rad_bill_id,price
    from rad_billing
    where patient_id = Pid;

    insert into sample2(patient)
    values(Pid);

    insert into sample2(physician)
    select attending_id
    from attending_physician
    where attending_physician.patient_id = Pid;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you're misunderstanding something about `INSERT`. Each time you `INSERT`, you create a *new* row. It doesn't add data to more columns in rows you recently created in prior `INSERT` statements.

So you need to get the patient and physician onto the rows you're inserting. The `Pid` is easy, you already have that as a variable and you can just put that in your `SELECT` as a third column. For the physician, you should use `JOIN` to append a column from the attending_physician table to the columns of your union of five billing-data queries.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Biller`(IN Pid varchar(30))
BEGIN
    insert into sample2(ids, prices, patient, physician)
    select b.bill_id, b.price, Pid, ph.attending_id
    from (
        select bed_bill_id as bill_id,price 
        from bed_billing
        where patient_id = Pid
        UNION
        select csr_bill_id,price
        from csr_billing
        where patient_id = Pid
        UNION
        select lab_bill_id,price
        from lab_billing
        where patient_id = Pid
        UNION
        select pharm_bill_id,price
        from pharm_billing
        where patient_id = Pid
        UNION
        select rad_bill_id,price
        from rad_billing
        where patient_id = Pid
    ) as b
    cross join attending_physician as ph
    where ph.patient_id = Pid;

END
```

Comment: that's what i'm thinking about the insert too. but when I tried your query, it says that `unknown column 'b.bill_id' in 'field list' `

Comment: I already solved it. using your query. the problem was `b.bill_id` but the other column's name are different so i just put `AS bill_id` in the select query. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I forgot to do that. I just edited the above to include that alias. FWIW you only need to alias the column in the first unioned query. The subsequent unioned queries will adopt the column names according to the first query.